# FormData image is undefined in post request with Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, fetch

i am using a profile picture file upload system,my HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageUpload" >
                        <img  id="profileImage" src="./images/avatar.png">
                        <button  type="button">
                        <input type="file" name="image" id="inpFile" class="hidden" onchange="uploadPicture(this)">
                        <label for="inpFile">Download</label></button>
```

my script :

```
 async function uploadPicture(input) {
    
//show user the image
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#profileImage').attr('src', e.target.result)
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }

        const form = document.querySelector('#imageUpload')//tried to send form.image.value before
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("inpFile", input.files[0]);
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/my-profile-image-upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData)),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
        } catch (error) 
            console.log(error);
    }
```

So I am sending this file inside an object but in my controller

```
module.exports.upload_picture = (req, res) => {
    const { FormData } = req.body;
    console.log(FormData);
}
```

I am getting undefined.
My goal is to store this image in my public folder since it is visible to all users and store the file name in the database, but I am not able to send this file using fetch. And I do have

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

in my app.js file

Any ideas on how to send this image using fetch?

Comment: You can't stringify a FormData object and it must use multipart content type header which it should set itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined because you have no middleware for handling multipart/form-data, for uploading files. You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to access the req.file object.